# uploading images to storage firebase not working

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I have an android app which uses firebase storage to save images, i honestly don't know what is wrong it used to work (haven't really changed anything) and when i place breakpoints it also works but when i just use the app the images don't get saved.

here is how i upload them to firebase:

```kotlin
 fun writeRoute(route: TrackerModel) {
        val user = User()
        val routeUser = database.getReference("/Routes").child(user.getUserEmailForDatabase())

        routeUser.child(route.guid.toString()).child("userEmail").setValue(route.userEmail)
        routeUser.child(route.guid.toString()).child("locations").setValue(route.getLocations())
        routeUser.child(route.guid.toString()).child("totalDistance").setValue(route.getTotalDistance())
        routeUser.child(route.guid.toString()).child("startDate").setValue(route.startDate)
        routeUser.child(route.guid.toString()).child("endDate").setValue(route.endDate)
        routeUser.child(route.guid.toString()).child("guid").setValue(route.guid)
        routeUser.child(route.guid.toString()).child("markers").setValue(route.getAllMarkers().map { marker -> marker.key })
        routeUser.child(route.guid.toString()).child("name").setValue(route.name)

        // write markers with bitmaps
        val images  = storage.getReference("/Images")
        val currentRouteImages = images.child(route.guid.toString())
        // k is of type LatLng and v is a Bitmap
        for ((k,v) in route.getAllMarkers()){
            if (v != null){
                val value = "PromenApp_${route.guid}_${k.latitude}_${k.longitude}.JPG"
                val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                v.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos)
                val data = baos.toByteArray()
                currentRouteImages.child(value).putBytes(data)
                    .addOnFailureListener{
                        println("error has occured while writing to storage")
                        it.printStackTrace();
                    }.addOnSuccessListener {
                        Log.d("Storage", "Image uploaded succesfully")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

here is where i call the method:

```kotlin
btnStopTracking.setOnClickListener{
            if (tracking) {
                val popup = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                val inflater = layoutInflater
                val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.save_route, null)
                popup.setView(view)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { popup, _ ->
                        val textview = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.route_name)
                        controller.setName(textview.text.toString())
                        controller.stopTracking()
                        controller.writeToDatabase()
                        Log.d("DB", "Written to database")
                        // redirect to home page
                        startActivity(Intent(this, Home::class.java));
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { popup, _ ->
                        controller.stopTracking();
                        // redirect to home page
                        startActivity(Intent(this, Home::class.java));
                    })
                popup.show()
            }else{
                // add current point as starting point
                controller.addLocation(currentLocation);
                tracking = true;
                startStopButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop_tracking)
                controller.startTracking()
            }
        }
```

Thanks for any help you can offer me.

stacktrace asked for in comments, however i don't think it is related to firebase

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lu@ef67976
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1562)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1692)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:717)
        at ci.f(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516068@20.45.16 (100700-0):1)
        at ci.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516068@20.45.16 (100700-0):2)
        at lv.E(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516068@20.45.16 (100700-0):9)
        at lf.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516068@20.45.16 (100700-0):3)
        at ef.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516068@20.45.16 (100700-0):3)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at iy.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516068@20.45.16 (100700-0):5)
```

Comment: Does your failure listener get called? If so please post the error stacktrace

Comment: no nor my own message nor the stacktrace are printed

Comment: i do however get this stacktrace, but i don't think it is related to firebase

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that after i saved it another function was called that wanted to read it, and this caused the issue.